# How can I add minus px to my plugin?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using a plugin to make equal my divs for example: [matchheight jquery plugin](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height) and I make what I want nearly, as you see on my demo my two divs are equal but I want to make a little specific:

my `.b` div must be little short than `.a` div, for example -15px or -10px..and my question is how can I add custom -px ?

```js
$('.b').matchHeight({
        target: $('.a')
    });
```

```css
.a,.b{
color:#fff;
padding:10px;
width:100px;
overflow:hidden;
float:left;
margin:5px;
}
.a{
background:red;
}
.b{
background:orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
<div class="b">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
</div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.matchHeight/0.7.2/jquery.matchHeight-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll probably need to adjust your "b" element after the plugin has adjust the heights. So you'll need to do that in the callback function after the update.

```
$.fn.matchHeight._afterUpdate = function(event, groups) {
  $('.b').height(function(){ return $('.b').height() - 10; });
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for the codes I couldn't try this code because code return error "unexpected token"

Comment: Oops, I forgot a semicolon and curly brace. Try now.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the codepen link, that helped me see. My spelling always gets me in trouble. I misspelled function. Also I didn't need the 'px' in there. Lastly in your codepen you didn't have your original js. ```$('.b').matchHeight({
        target: $('.a')
    });``` Add that to the beginning as well as my fixes and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

unless to rewrite the script, you might fake this in CSS with `border` and `background-clip` :

```
border-bottom:solid 10px/* set you size here */ transparent /* lets see through it */;
background-clip:padding-box;/* keep background away from the border */
```

```js
$('.b').matchHeight({
  target: $('.a')
});
```

```css
.a,
.b {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 3px black;
}

.a {
  background: red;
}

.b {
  background: orange;
  border-bottom: solid 15px transparent;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}

body {
  background: gray
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.
</div>
<div class="b">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.matchHeight/0.7.2/jquery.matchHeight-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: very well is that cross browser ?

Comment: and this remove my border :/

Comment: @ani_css caniuse.com to check support , border ? there were none in the question, was it ? Answer was for a simple css workaround and talk about background-clip that deserve to be known ;)

Comment: @ani_css just added black borders to the snippet .. feed back is apreciated ;)

Answer (score 0):

If using jquery, you can use the height method (or the css method) to get and set the height value, and do the actual calculation of subtracting 10 or 15 px using pure JavaScript.
If you want to use pure CSS and HTML, you can also use the calc feature in CSS, though a few browsers don't support it.

In some cases (namely, when trying to make the heights including the borders be equal), box-model: border-box may also help.

Comment: I need to do with jquery plugin I've no javascript experience and no need to css it's not cross browser I know..I try calc() and flexbox but I need cross solution thank you